# drop down menu with 2 imgs(links) on same line?

Tags: php, html

is there a way to get my drop down menu [submit] and [add] | [edit] imgs to be on the same line at the top?

```
    print "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n";
    print "<a href=\"$popup_href\" class=\"action_link\" title=\"Add\"><img src=\"images/add.png\" alt=\"Add\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
    print "<a href=\"daily.php?$ymdStr\" title=\"Edit\"><img src=\"images/edit.png\" alt=\"Edit\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
    print "<ul id=\"nav\" class=\"drop\">\n";
    print "<li onmouseover=\"\"><b>Submit</b>\n";
    print "<ul>\n";
    print "<li><a href=\"confirm.php?$ymdStr\">Timesheet</a></li>\n";
    print "<li><a href=\"overtime.php?$ymdStr\">Overtime</a></li>\n";
    print "</ul></li></ul></td>\n";
```

example pic: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... just had to make a new `<td>` and they are on same line now.

Fix:

```
        print "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n";
        print "<a href=\"$popup_href\" class=\"action_link\" title=\"Add\"><img src=\"images/add.png\" alt=\"Add\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "<a href=\"daily.php?$ymdStr\" title=\"Edit\"><img src=\"images/edit.png\" alt=\"Edit\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" border=\"0\"></a></td>\n";
        print "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n";
        print "<ul id=\"nav\" class=\"drop\">\n";
        print "<li onmouseover=\"\"><b>Submit</b>\n";
        print "<ul>\n";
        print "<li><a href=\"confirm.php?$ymdStr\">Timesheet</a></li>\n";
        print "<li><a href=\"overtime.php?$ymdStr\">Overtime</a></li>\n";
        print "</ul></li></ul></td>\n";
```